# Mongoose pagination case insensitive string sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using NodeJS 12 with Mongoose v5 and the mongoose-paginate-v2 plugin. It is working correctly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2

Question: Is it possible to set the 'sort' option to be case insensitive with the plugin?

The sort option is returning sorted values in case-sensitive order, so capital 'Z' is ordered before lowercase 'a'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have control over that with `collation` as part of the options as per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2#sample-usage):

```
const options = {
  page: 1,
  limit: 10,
  collation: {   // <--- setup the sorting options via the collation flags
    locale: 'en'
  }
};
```

Here is more on [Collation and its flags](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation). Your usage then would be just as expected:

```
Model.paginate({}, options, function(err, result) {
  // ....
});
```